# Trying to serve responsive custom code through DFP

Tags: responsive-design, ads, google-dfp

We're trying to serve simple markup - a thumbnail, image, and some text - through DFP. This markup needs to be fluid - it's one member of a responsive grid on our website.

Assuming we can't avoid the iframe, is there a way we can get the iframe to be set at 100% width? That would probably do it.

The issues we're having is that we're forced to define an ad unit size, and that seems to dictate the dimensions of the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the control over the iframe, the best solution would be to extract the content of the iframe and append it to the parent using javascript. This way you will be able to use your websites responsive grid and class.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Mathieu but you are wrong. DFP uses friendly iFrames and you can change the  width or height if you use your own creative template. We have many custom templates defined in DFP for our masthead variations that can expand, collapse, destroy ad unit's iframe.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?